# Highest integers common factor testing error

Tags: prolog, greatest-common-divisor

I would like the following `bar/3` predicate to print `false` if the integers `A` and `B` do not have `C` as highest common factor else it should print `true`,but as of now it's giving an error in case C is not HCF.
I am not sure how to fix this.

```
foo(P,Q,R):-L is P/Q,R is P-Q*floor(L).
bar(A,0,A).
bar(A,B,C):-foo(A,B,X),bar(B,X,C).
```

for example,in case of error,I am getting

```
?- bar(27,30,1).
ERROR: //2: Arithmetic: evaluation error: `zero_divisor'
```

instead of

```
?- bar(27,30,1).
false
```

and on success I get the correct result I want

```
?- bar(27,30,3).
true
```

Comment: If you're working with integers and their factors, why the trip to floats?

Comment: Your `L is P/Q, R is P - Q*floor(L)` could be written, `R is P - (P // Q)`.

Comment: Do a `trace` to see where you're allowing a zero (`0`) argument `Q` in your call to `foo/3`.

Comment: @lurker: For `P = -2, `Q = 3` you produce -2 in stead of 1. Use `div`. Or even simpler: `mod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is a cut missing. You want that the first clause
of bar/3 is executed for =0, and the second clause of bar/3
is executed for <>0. This can be done with a cut:

```
foo(P,Q,R):-L is P/Q,R is P-Q*floor(L).
bar(A,0,A) :- !.
bar(A,B,C):-foo(A,B,X),bar(B,X,C).
```

But the cut doesn't work correctly, if the third argument
is bound. Since the first clause might then fail because the
unification of the first argument and third argument fails,
and not because <>0.

So you need a second rewrite to make the predicate steadfast 
in the last argument:

```
foo(P,Q,R):-L is P/Q,R is P-Q*floor(L).
bar(A,0,B) :- !, B=A.
bar(A,B,C):-foo(A,B,X),bar(B,X,C).
```

Now everything works fine, as the following example run
shows:

```
 Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.22)
 Copyright (c) 1990-2014 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
 ?- bar(27,30,1).
 false.

 ?- bar(27,30,3).
 true.
```

Bye

BTW: You can extend the working range of the predicate 
tremendously, by not using floats, but the ordinary
integers, which are for most modern Prolog systems without
a fixed bound.

The code then reads as follows, using a more appropriate
predicate name:

```
gcd(X, 0, Y) :- !, Y = X.
gcd(X, Y, Z) :-
   H is X rem Y,
   gcd(Y, H, Z).
```